# Where is information about options for caption transitions

Tags: jssor

Is there any documentation that describes the various attributes this component utilizes?  In a div, I see u=caption, so I assume u is the attribute describing the what kind of element this is.  there are other attributes, such as d=-750, t=l, b=500, etc.

What are all these attributes, and how would I use them?

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="/Content/IMG_0381.jpg" />

                <div u=caption t="L" d=-750 b=500  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 300px; width:130px; height:30px;"> 
                hello world
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'u' (or 'data-u') attribute describes usage of element. To define html code for jssor slider, some elements should be specified with 'u' attribute. e.g. u="slides', u="image", u="caption', u="navigator', u="arrowleft", u="arrowleft", u="thumbnavigator" and so on.

For attributes to define caption, see http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html

For all in information, please read [Jssor Slider development documentation](http://www.jssor.com/development/).